# How to exclude unnecessary unmanaged dependencies from packaging?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I want to create a standalone version of my application and was wondering how i could exclude 
an unmanaged *.jar file to be packaged. It's the "mariaDB4j-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" file I **solely 
use in tests** which is about 56MB huge.

I tried to put the jar file into a custom directory 'test/lib'. Unfortunately, this did not exclude mariaDB4j from packaging.

```
unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "test/lib" }

unmanagedJars in Test <<= unmanagedBase  map { base => (base ** "mariaDB4j-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar").classpath }
```

Any thoughts on this?

Cheers 
Oliver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to add to the testing classpath.

Two things:

1. You can check out what's on the classpath using `show test:fullClasspath` to make sure your jar is on there.   Using `inspect test:fullClasspath` will show you what the dependencies used for testing are.
2. I think you can directly add your jar to the classpath via:

   fullClasspath in Test += Attributed.blank(baseDirectory.value / "test/lib/mariaDB4j-2.0-SNAPSHOT")

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for answering. It does not work. The mariaDB4j-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is not usable, it's not compiled. All tests are failing. After executing dist the mariaDB4j-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is not packed. That's half the battle...

Comment: Are you adding a file that's compiled by the current project?

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it looks a little overstated. Changing the base directory of the unmanaged dependencies, include the file to the test's and exclude it from compile.

```
unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "test/lib" }

unmanagedJars in Test <<= unmanagedBase  map { base => (base ** "mariaDB4j-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar").classpath }

excludeFilter in unmanagedJars in Compile := "mariaDB4j-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

excludeFilter in unmanagedJars in Compile ~= { _ || "mariaDB4j-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" }
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use unmanaged dependencies

if you want to keep the jar in your source repository just use a file based maven repository in your source tree with

```
resolvers += "Private Maven Repository" at file(".").toURI.toURL+"/repository"
```

then mvn install MariaDB4j locally and copy resulting stuff from maven cache to $yourproject/repository

and use the dependency like a regular managed dependency

Comment: Could u maybe post an example which shows how to use  the dependency like a regular managed dependency either how to exclude mariaDB4j from  packaging?

Comment: libraryDependencies += "ch.vorburger.mariaDB4j" % "mariaDB4j" % "2.0-SNAPSHOT" % "test"